# Best way to shorten item's names in lists, but retaining per-item uniqueness?

Tags: gui-design, lists

We have a drop-down menu for the user to switch between several accounts or profiles, and these accounts are identified by their legal entity name. There's a higher than random chance that many of the names for a given user would be very similar, as in the following:

- Proactive Plumbing Inc.
- Proactive Plumbing QLD Division P/L
- Proactive Plumbing New South Wales
- Proactive Plumbing, Bedrooms, and Kitchens
- Proactive Plumbing Workers Pension Fund New South Wales

The problem is that we don't want to show the full length name in the drop-down menu, as it could become unwieldy in width. Similarly, we can't simply truncate or elide on some blind rule.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Some sanity prevails - the business stakeholders will compromise on the potential maximum string length, reducing from 100 characters down to 50 characters. Still too long of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possibility I

Why don't you use `title` attribute so when user pauses mouse cursor on such item, a hint/tooltip would display the whole text. This can also be used for a custom tooltip solution that would display tooltip immediately when element is too wide.

### Possibility II

Second possibility is to use custom drop down solution with shifting element content. So when a wider (by content) element is paused on it would automatically get scrolled to the right to reveal all content. This is somehow similar to phone phonebooks which had names wider than screen with could deliver. Names simply got scrolled to the right.

### Outcome?

The first one is of course faster for users to use. And using some custom tooltip solution it could as well mean that positioning of the tooltip may be crucial to usability to make things as fast to use as possible.

The second on seems somehow more natural, but depending on the text length and shifting speed it may take some time to get to the *unique* part of the content.

Comment: Eeew. Autoscrolling? No thanks. Unless it is only auto-scrolled when the mouse is near a left or right edge.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: Implementation is of course on the implementer. Could just as well have a right side *bar* similar to Win7 taskbar that would scroll the item when moused over it.

Comment: yes, there are plenty of options to implement it, I just wanted to express my dislike of UI's that try to be helpful automatically but really only take control away from me. I used to hate the auto-scrolling in the Windows Explorer until the sensitive area became smaller and the pause before scrolling longer. Similar with auto-scrolling in Word when dragging text. I never could get Word to stop where I wanted it to until it slowed down the scrolling...

Answer (score 4):

If you detect 4 or more consecutive items with more than 1 word repeating at the beginning, group them:

```
Proactive Plumbing
 ... Inc.
 ... QLD Division P/L
 ... New South Wales
 ..., Bedrooms, and Kitchens
 ... Workers Pension Fund New South Wales
Something completely different
```

Comment: Ah, good insight - if there exist similar names, the similarity is likely to be at the start of the name and that can be elided.

Comment: This is a really nice way of doing it but there's a caveat to this pattern... It's hard(er) to find the correct item when they're alphabetically ordered because when an item has many variants you don't see where you are, when original item is above the visible box. Maybe at least keep the first letter before ellipsis to keep usability of alphabetic ordering... Like: **P... QLT Division P/L**

Comment: **Another problem:** What if you had *Proactive America*, *Proactive Inc.*, *Proactive Overseas Ltd.*, *Proactive Worldwide* and then a few of *Proactive Plumbing ...* How should your truncation work in this case? Should all fall under *Proactive* or should they be segregated on repeated pattern?

Comment: @RobertKoritnik, I think that if there’s enough data in each category (>3-4 in Proactive America, Proactive Plumbing) they should be collapsed separately. Collapsing just a single word may not worth it at all.

Comment: @Nikita: You do realise that locating these *split points* in strings (especially in cases some set is a subset of the other) is not as simple as it seems to be to humans. Algorithm should actually create sets of items with same first word. Then recursively do the same thing on every set while cutting off the first word (and counting set sizes to only create sets of 3+ items). A nice development problem actually. :)

Comment: @RobertKoritnik: 1 hour to develop and test by my estimation.

Comment: Well of course when I already sketched it out for you... ;) And 1 hour seems to be the usual optimistic developer's estimate that would be off by another hour. :)

Comment: My algorithm doesn't take into account cases when certain items start repeating in the part that's not visible anymore (too wide). There are probably even more edge cases that your 1 hour solution (with tests) should cover and you haven't envisioned. But that of course is a different problem. Your solution of how to do this is still marvellous.

Comment: Do we have a UX.SE tag for np-hard yet?